# Left join doesn't return all results from first table

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a table that is used for reference (number), as follows

```
----------------------------
Id | Name | Description    |
----------------------------
1    One    The number one
2    Two    The number two
3    Three  The number three
```

And then another table (user_number) that references these values but for specific users

```
--------------------------
Id | User_Id | Number_Id |
--------------------------
1    400      1
2    400      2
```

I want to retrieve all the results of the first table but I want to see where they match up also. I have tried to use the following query but it only returns what an INNER JOIN would return

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON n.Id = un.Id
WHERE un.User_Id = 400;
```

This query returns:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "One",
        "Description": "The number one",
        "Active_Number": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Two",
        "Description": "The number two",
        "Active_Number": 2
    }
]
```

However this doesn't return the third set of values from the number table.

Comment: Sure it doesn't, your `WHERE` clause makes sure of that.

Comment: its about when to put multiple on in joins vs where

Comment: 1. Your partial description of what you want disagrees with your partial description of your desired output & what your wrong query suggests--because you don't mention =400. And you don't actually say how or show how the desired output looks like the input--even for your example. 2. Read a *definition* of left join. It returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. When you think you want a left join because all left table participate, get clear on what the associated inner join is. Also your where clearly can't return ids without a 400, so you know that is wrong.

Comment: This is a faq. *Googling your title returns many appropriate answers.* The "related" list on the left includes the duplicate above. Such duplicates were offered when you typed your question. Please google 'philipxy google many phrasings'. PS Please format tables as tables. It's good that you did give a lot of info. Still, please read [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy While your comments are helpful the way you present yourself in them is not. The comments come off as rude, condescending, and presumptuous. I did not find the duplicate of this easily and it did not come up when I was typing the title, I clicked on all of the related questions that came up when I created my question and that was not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is making this into an `INNER JOIN`.  Put that in the `ON` clause instead:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON n.Id = un.Id
AND un.User_Id = 400;
```

Comment: how is your sql different from OP ?

Comment: That works perfectly. I didn't even think the culprit was in the `WHERE` clause. I tried `EXCEPT` and `UNION` to try to make it work and nothing returned everything.

Comment: @Rajaji `un.User_Id = 400` is in the join condition instead of the where clause.  Since a left join will leave nulls on records that don't join, having a `WHERE` filter against the right table will essentially make it an inner join.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy I've spent way more time than I'd like to admit racking my brain about this exact scenario.  It's easy to overlook, happy to help.

Comment: I guess the join would work only if there was **LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON  un.User_Id = 400;**

Answer (score 2):

Dont' know what DB you're using but try

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON n.Id = un.Id and un.User_Id = 400;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because in your where condition, you are eliminating all records where User ID is not 400 - which excludes any row in the left table, but not the right.

Based on the where condition placement, you're applying that filter to the whole query, AFTER the join. What you should od instead is this:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN (select * from user_number 
WHERE un.User_Id = 400 ) un
ON n.Id = un.Id;
```

EDIT: the other responder's answer is the better choice, which eluded me when I was typing up this code - which works also, but is not the ideal solution.

Comment: I think your idea is more logical than the others and had put it in my own answer as well before seeing that you already suggested the same.

Comment: @hvd & Stassi There are always multiple ways of writing things but this is not as simple as one left join. The simplest left join definition is inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So here, given that we want a left join because we want all left table rows, and we have to identify the condition for the associated join, there's no reason to split up the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEFT JOIN` *does* return all results from the first table. Here's the result of the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Description     | Id | User_Id | Number_Id |
-------------------------------------------------------
1    One    The number one    1    400       1
2    Two    The number two    2    400       2
3    Three  The number three  NULL NULL      NULL
```

Here, if you filter on `User_Id = 400`, it should be obvious why the third row is excluded.

A common suggestion when seeing these results is changing the filter to `WHERE User_Id IS NULL OR User_Id = 400`. **Don't do this.**

Suppose you have other records in your second table with a different user ID, so that the left join result looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Description     | Id | User_Id | Number_Id |
-------------------------------------------------------
1    One    The number one    1    400       1
2    Two    The number two    2    400       2
2    Two    The number two    3    500       2
3    Three  The number three  4    500       3
```

Here, it should be obvious that again, you'd be removing the last row.

The other answers you've received about moving the `WHERE` condition to the join condition will work, but a more logical, IMO, approach is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM user_number
    WHERE user_id = 400
) AS un
ON n.Id = un.Id;
```

This reduces the data set to which you're joining, to only the data to which you actually want to join. But the result is the same as putting the `user_id = 400` check in the join condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Always put the join conditions in the on clause** If you are doing an inner join, so do not add any where conditions to the on clause, put them in the where clause

If you are doing a **left join**, add any where conditions to the on clause for the table in the right side of the join. This is a must because adding a where clause that references the right side of the join will convert the join to an inner join (With one exception described below).

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON n.Id = un.Id
AND un.User_Id = 400;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the WHERE condition and it will work as you intended. What you are doing basically is getting the left join correctly and then filtering out the 3rd row.

If you want to get all 3 results you can do:

```
SELECT n.Id, n.Name, n.Description, un.Id As Active_Number
FROM number n
LEFT JOIN user_number un
ON n.Id = un.Id
WHERE u.Id < 4;
```

In other words, the table you should be filtering is the left one on the left join (number).